# CloudFormation nested stack parameter conversion from String/ComaDelimitedList to 'mappings Key-Value pairs'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am passing a parameter from a cloudformation master stack to a nested stack for *RequestParameters* property of *'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'* resource.

The supported CloudFormation Parameter types (DataType) are: *String*, *Number*,  *List*, *CommaDelimitedList* and AWS-Specific Parameter Types as specified here:

Is it possible to set the parameter value as *String* ( or *CommaDelimitedList* ) and in the nested stack to convert it into mappings key-value pairs as  *RequestParameters* property of *'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'* resource requires it?

A mapping of key-value pairs would look like this:

```
Resources:
  LambdaEndpointMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.querystring.param1 : true
        method.request.querystring.param2 : true
        method.request.querystring.param3 : true
```

I have already tried specifying the parameter type String and passing all key-value pairs as comma separated strings then using Fn::Split intrinsic function to split the string but cloudformation complains with an error  `Value of property RequestParameters must be an object`.

this is my nested stack template:

```
Parameters:
  RequestParametersString:
    Description: List of request parameters
    Type: String
    Default: ''

...

Conditions:
  EmptyRequestParametersString: !Equals [ !Ref RequestParametersString, '' ]

...

Resources:
  LambdaEndpointMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      RequestParameters: !If [ EmptyRequestParametersString, 'AWS:NoValue', !Split [',', !Ref RequestParametersList] ]
```

and this is my master template:

```
  MyNestedStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: ...
      Parameters:
         ...
        RequestParametersString: 'method.request.querystring.param1 : true, method.request.querystring.param2 : true, method.request.querystring.param3 : false'
```

Is there any way how to achieve this on cloudformation or could somebody provide a solution of how to pass a couple of key-value pairs from master to child stack as a parameter?